# Отображение CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вообщем у меня есть CoordinatorLayout и мну нужно его редактировать, но проблема в том, что его preview не отображается в android Studio? А запускать по 500 раз приложение в эмуляторе не самый лучший вариант. Ну дак вот, как мне седлать чтобы оно отображалось ?? Вот что я вижу в preview на данный момент. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще подобные моменты там с DrawableLayout и еще парочка, но у них хотя бы границы видно так что я примерно знаю что будет видеть пользователь, а тут хз.
Код CoordiantorLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/white_cl"
tools:context="ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_data"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/arr_left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_arr_left"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

        <ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital.FontsOverride
            app:font="CoHeadlineCorp.ttf"
            android:id="@+id/txt_data_up"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white_cl"
            />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/arr_right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style_arr_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt_LeftMenu"
    android:src="@drawable/menu"
    android:background="#80aa00"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:onClick="f_menu"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|start" android:focusable="true"/>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt_RightMenu"
    android:src="@drawable/filtr"
    android:background="#80aa00"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
    android:onClick="f_menu"
    android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"/>




<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_act"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_width="23pt"
    android:layout_height="23pt"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_circle2"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="23pt"
    android:layout_height="23pt"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/krug_bt_style"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/minus_change_bg"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/minus_change"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30pt"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusable="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt_in_circle"
    android:src="@drawable/del"
    android:background="@drawable/roz_bt_style"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30pt"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/obmen_change_bg"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/obmen_change"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60pt"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt_in_circle2"
    android:src="@drawable/mej_schet"
    android:background="@drawable/krug_bt_style"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60pt"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/plus_change_bg"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plus_change"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30pt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt_in_circle3"
    android:src="@drawable/small_add"
    android:background="@drawable/krug_bt_style"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30pt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/komment_window"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/komment_layout"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollKomment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital.FontsOverride                 app:font="CoHeadlineCorp.ttf"
            android:id="@+id/komment_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/komment_close"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/green_culc_bt_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white_cl"
        android:text="@string/str_close"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/del_window"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/komment_layout"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital.FontsOverride                 app:font="CoHeadlineCorp.ttf"
            android:id="@+id/are_you_shure_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/are_you_shure_str"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delschet_layout_alert"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_del_str"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/green_culc_bt_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white_cl"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delstrintable"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bt_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white_cl"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<include layout="@layout/reluat_operacion" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Похоже на то, что библиотека support:design не подключена в проект

Comment: @pavlofff это что за библиотека такая ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включите использование дополнительной библиотеки support:design от гугла. Эта библиотека поддерживает использование основных эленментов API и шаблонов проектирования, так что маст хев!

Подключение в градле:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Доп [инфо](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html)